# Connecting to Hadoop with Python

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop

I have 2 user account in Ubunthu 14.04 namely user and hduser. 
I have setup Hadoop (stand-alone) in hduser. 
Now I have a python program running in user account, which need access hadoop to put data in to hdfs.

ie,

```
su hduser
password : XXX
hdfs dfs -put  data.txt
```

How this can be done in Python?